# Puppet package resource

Tags: puppet

Have a basic doubt about puppet package resource.If I have a package resource declared in the the manifest file for eg:to install apache using apt-get.

1.During the first run of puppet agent,apache will get installed.

2.If I run the agent(using the existing code for package resource) again after ubuntu repo is refreshed with latest version of apache.

Will puppet update/refresh the apache in agent server?

Answer (score 1):

The Package's `ensure` attribute determines the state.

> What state the package should be in. On packaging systems that can retrieve new packages on their own, you can choose which package to retrieve by specifying a version number or latest as the ensure value. On packaging systems that manage configuration files separately from “normal” system files, you can uninstall config files by specifying purged as the ensure value. This defaults to installed.
>
> Version numbers must match the full version to install, including release if the provider uses a release moniker. Ranges or semver patterns are not accepted except for the gem package provider. For example, to install the bash package from the rpm bash-4.1.2-29.el6.x86_64.rpm, use the string '4.1.2-29.el6'.
>
> Valid values are present (also called installed), absent, purged, held, latest. Values can match /./.

Source: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/package.html#package-attribute-ensure